Почему Laravel 8 перестал выводить ошибки?
Перестали выводится ошибки , только 500-я , в логах такие записи
[Sun May 19 18:09:19.580983 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1698665] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:58308] mod_fcgid: stderr: <b>PHP Fatal error:</b>  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 266240 bytes) in /var/www/lobochkin28/data/www/lobochkin.ru/laravel-blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php on line 215, referer: http://laravel-blog.lobochkin.ru/admin/category
[Sun May 19 18:09:19.581149 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1698665] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:58308] mod_fcgid: stderr: <b>PHP Fatal error: </b> Uncaught Error: Class "Monolog\\Utils" not found in /var/www/lobochkin28/data/www/lobochkin.ru/laravel-blog/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:58, referer: http://laravel-blog.lobochkin.ru/admin/category
[Sun May 19 18:09:19.581182 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1698665] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:58308] mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:, referer: http://laravel-blog.lobochkin.ru/admin/category


Ошибку я исправил , но если я делаю допустим ошибку в синтаксисе , то всё равно получаю в браузере 500

Помогла переустановка Monolog
composer require monolog/monolog

